# How to enable SQL Server Agent in SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

When I try to start SQL Server Agent from SQL Server Configuration Manager
I get this error

> the request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion.Consult the error log or other applicable error log for details

So how can I solve it?

Comment: SQL Server **Express** does **NOT** include the Agent ..... you can solve this by **buying a valid license** for a web, standard, developer or enterprise edition - which all include the SQL Server Agent. See [SQL Server Feature Comparison by Edition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc645993.aspx) for details

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if your sqlServerAgent is running in windows admin tools / services? If it is stopped,just right click it and start it. Set also start type to automatic in next column.

Comment: I didn't but how could I? can you tell me plz@DaddyCool

Comment: what version of windows? Win7: control panel / admin tools / services

Comment: I have checked on a server where express is installed and unfortunately you cannot start the service even if it is showing up in the service list.

Answer (score 1):

The agent service is not included in the express editions of SQL Server, so it can't be enabled at all. Even though the error messages are misleading, the actual error is a licensing one. To get the agent you need to upgrade to any other edition. For just developing and testing the developer edition is the best choice.

Other than that, you can try to emulate such functionality by using the Windows task scheduler to run the SQL command line tools.

Comment: At least as-of 2016 SP1 (and maybe prior versions), the Agent *is* included but it will not run for Express

Comment: @Schneider Well, technically yes, it's included and just refuses to run, but considering the licensing saying that it doesn't includes the agent, in practice it's reasonable to say that Express edition does *not* include it. The OP itself just found it and it simply don't runs.